# Can my code malfunction or bring up an error if two or more users take the same action at a time

Tags: php, laravel

I was told by a senior programmer in my school that if two or more user do the same action at a time the code will start malfunctioning or will bring up errors.

Please i want to know if such a thing can happen.

Comment: Where's your code...

Comment: its not a specific code. He was talking about all my codes. Actually i'm using laravel to do the coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but that is more of a concern of your servlet, as a PHP developer, you would use a servlet that someone else written (Apache server). This is more coming to play if you're coding on language such as JAVA, with Java you can write your own servlet to handle incoming request (some thing that Apache Server would do); as a PHP developer you wouldn't need to worry about this as you'll be using a pre-written servlet. If you need to know about this heres a [Servlet tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-tutorial). If you want to know about solution for it read up on [Volatile](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html) objects or variables

Comment: So you are saying such a thing cannot happen in php unless i'm writing a servlet. right?

Comment: In theory Yes, thats the whole purpose of LAMP or XAMPP servers. Unless you some how mess around with the built in servlet and its thread functionality

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputations to upvote your answer

Comment: Thats ok, glad I could help :)

Comment: I appreciate bro.